# UITableView: Number of elements in footer in the last section

Tags: ios, uitableview, footer

I would like to know how can I make appear in the last section of a `UITableView` the number of elements in the table as in iPhone Contacts App:

[image: Sample]

Thank you

Comment: Did you try, to add just another row with the number of entries you have? Or if its really in the footer, what about adding a footer just to the last section using e same style like your normal rows?! Just some ideas :-)

Comment: I think it is just a regular pretty-formatted UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch rows count from table sections like this:

```
int rowCount = 0;

for(int SECTION_NUMBER = 0 ; SECTION_NUMBER < numOfSections ; i++)
{

    rowCount += [tablePropertyName numberOfRowsInSection:SECTION_NUMBER];
}
```

Here **rowCount** will be total of all rows.
So you can show rowCount in tablefooter method

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    //Here pass rowCount in label text
}.
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I think it's the only possibility.
Do you know what font can I use to make it looks like that shown in picture?

Comment: No but I think you can check this by taking an snapshot and then use photoshop for getting font

Answer (score 1):

You can add a tablview delegate method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    //add a uilabel with number of contacts text 
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tableFooterView property of UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableFooterView).